# зависание вывода nohup

Tags: python, subprocess, nohup

Есть скрипт на python который запускает другие скрипты следующим образом:

```
subprocess.Popen(['nohup', 'python3', '/folder/sqript.py'],
             stdout=open('/folder/sqript.log', 'a'),
             stderr=open('/folder/sqript.log', 'a'),
             preexec_fn=os.setpgrp )
```

После чего командой tail -f, слежу за их работой. Если запускать скрипты с сервака напрямую, то логи идут нормально без подвисаний. Если же запускать через скрипт, то они начинают выдаваться с задержкой. Как этого избежать?

Comment: Господи... А почему вы код на Питоне таким странным образом из кода на Питоне запускаете?

Comment: Управление ботами, через телегу